# Linux save string to file without ECHO command

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I want to save a command to a file (for example I want to save the string "cat /etc/passwd" to a file) but I can't use the echo command.

How can I create and save string to a file directly without using echo command?

Comment: If you're trying to save the contents of one file (i.e. `/etc/passwd`) to another, why not just use `cp`?

Comment: It would be helpful to know why you can't use the echo command, so that we'd know what alternatives are acceptable. Is this a class assignment? An obfuscated shell script contest?

Answer (score 2):

You can redirect `cat` to a file, type the text, and press Control-D when you're done, like this:

```
cat > file.txt
some text
some more text
^D
```

By `^D` I mean to press Control-D at the end. The line must be empty.
It will not be part of the file, it is just to terminate the input.

Answer (score 1):

```
 { { command ls $(dirname $(which cat)) | 
    grep ^ca't$'; ls /etc/passwd; } | 
    tr \\n ' '; printf '\n'; }  > output-file
```

But it's probably a lot simpler to just do : `printf 'cat /etc/passwd\n'`

To be clear, this is a tongue-in-cheek solution.  The initial command is an extraordinarily convoluted way to get what you want, and this is intended to be a humorous answer.  Perhaps instructive to understand.

Answer (score 1):

Are you avoiding ECHO for **security purposes** (e.g. you're using a shared terminal and you don't want to leave trace in the shell history of what you've written inside your files) or you're **just curious** for an alternative method?

---

**Simple alternative to echo:**

As someone said, redirecting *cat* is probably the simpler way to go.
I'd suggest you to manually type your end-of-file, like this:

```
cat <<EOF > outputfile

> type here
> your 
> text
> and finish it with
> EOF
```

Here's the string you're asking for, as an example:

```
 cat <<EOF > myscript.sh
    cat /etc/passwd
    EOF
```

You probably don't want everyone to know you've peeked into that file, but if that's your purpose please notice that wrapping it inside an executable file won't make it more private, as that lines will be logged anyway...

---

**Security - Avoiding history logs etc..**

In modern shell, just try adding a space at the beginning of every command and use freely whatever you want.

BTW, my best hint is to *avoid using that terminal at all*, if you can. If you got two shells (another machine or even just another secure user in the same machine), I'd recommend you using *netcat*. See here: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/04/nc-command-examples/?utm_source=feedburner

Comment: Now that you mention security, another use is for passing password to stdin of an application. If `echo` is used then the password can be seen via `ps`.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understood you correctly but

```
    cat /etc/passwd > target.file
```

use the > operator to write it to file without echoing

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use it, inside a program :

```
cat <<EOF >file.txt
some text
some more text
EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine that you are probably trying to print the content of a string to a file, hence you mentioned `echo`.

You are avoiding this:

```
echo "cat /etc/passwd" > target.file
```

You can use a here string combined with `cat`.

```
cat > target.file <<< "cat /etc/passwd"
```

Now the file `target.file` will contain a string `cat /etc/passwd`.

```
$ cat target.file
cat /etc/passwd
$
```

Answer (score 0):

To create string: 
var1=`your command`
to save a file or variable in a file without echo use:
cat $FILE/VAR1 > /new/file/path